# Prevent Dropdown expand on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"></i></span>
        <span class="txt">Smartr Sites</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li>
            <a href="tables.html">
                <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"></i></span>
                <span class="txt">Chicken Notes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="data-tables.html">
                <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"></i></span>
                <span class="txt">Purely Commerce</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My Dashboard Submenu automatically expands without having a click on page load. and i only want to expand or close when i click it .
may be it can be done through JS tweak.

[image]

Comment: Please share a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example. We can't possibly deduce the styles based on a screenshot.

Comment: can you share at the least the JS code that trigger the dropdown ?

Comment: My guess is you need to set the right class. Impossible to answer since we have no clue about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for helping out but i found a way to make this happen . I just put the id in dropdown menu and applied a JS function related to that id Here it is:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"id="posuvnik">
        <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"> 
     </i></span>
        <span class="txt">Smartr Sites</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li>
            <a href="tables.html">
                <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"></i></span>
                <span class="txt">Chicken Notes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="data-tables.html">
                <span class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-stack-list"></i></span>
                <span class="txt">Purely Commerce</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

</script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#posuvnik").click();
  });
</script>
```